# Create playlist with JPlayer Circle Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jplayer

I know it wasn't meant for that in particular, but does anyone know how I can make the [JPlayer Circle Player](http://jplayer.org/) play songs from a Playlist? I would like it to play song after song and loop the entire playlist (if possible.) when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the playlist in a json object which contains the list of songs you want to play on the server.  Then when a song ends, there's an ended function of the jPlayer object which you can override, then call the play event again with the next song on the playlist.

Documentation to the play function:
http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play